# Потерял доступ к windows установив ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

Хотел установить ubuntu второй системой к своей винде, но наковырял что-то не то и в итоге установил убунту, НО зайти в винду не могу, должна вылазить менюшка с выбором операционки, но после загрузки биоса сразу запускается линукс. Однако винда все еще на диске и я имею доступ к ней со своей линукс в /win
могу ли я все же выбрать винду второй системой?
Хочу восстановить доступ к винде, как это сделать?
Подмечу, что диск в ноуте один, обе операционки на нём

Comment: А если через биос посмотреть-какой приоритет загрузки? Там указан диск с виндой или убунту?

Comment: пробовал, там только один диск, и нет выбора, что запускать

Comment: А как вы устанавливали убунту? Вы ведь разделили диск на 2 через через "Управление дисками", а потом установили убунту на свободную отделенную часть?

Comment: я разделил диск на 2 уже при установке убунту

Comment: после чего на свободное пространство установил убунту, а на занятое выделил как /win

Comment: Хм тогда хз, я во всех гайдах по установке видел, что заранее место выделяют, не знаю что вызывает проблему тогда, ща мб найду что то

Answer (score 1):

Короче нашел в чем скорее всего проблема-при установке Ubuntu, устанавливается загрузчик GRUB, который обычно настраивается таким образом, чтобы Ubuntu была выбрана по умолчанию и загружалась автоматически первой.

Чтоб при включении был выбор ОС:

1)В терминале выполните команду `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`, чтобы открыть файл конфигурации GRUB в текстовом редакторе Nano.

2)В открывшемся файле найдите строку, начинающуюся с `GRUB_DEFAULT=`. Здесь определяется операционная система, которая будет выбрана по умолчанию.

3)Измените значение переменной `GRUB_DEFAULT` на `saved`, чтобы сохранить выбор предыдущей операционной системы.

4)Ниже строки `GRUB_DEFAULT=` добавьте новую строку: `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true`.

5)Сохраните изменения в файле, нажав клавиши Ctrl+O.

6)В терминале выполните команду `sudo update-grub`, чтобы применить изменения.

На всякий случай уточню, при обновлении ядра Ubuntu или GRUB, изменения могут слететь, тк файл перезапишется и придется заново прописывать его.